# uilabel custom positioning with constraints in uipickerview

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I want to have custom UILabel inside UIPickerView which is right aligned and with width = half of the screen width:

[image]

How to position everything with NSConstraints? I had some problems since UILabel was not attached to super view when I have a chance to modify it.

I managed to get it working but it is not done with NSConstraints and is probably wrong (I was able to set up frame if I embeded UILabel inside another view). Any suggestions how to do it properly?

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0f, width / 2 + 18, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    lbl.text = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:row];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    lbl.font=[UIFont CPGeneralFontWithSize:22];

    [newView addSubview:lbl];

    return newView;
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure about this but i remember i've read here on SO that you kinda need to cheat with labels and aligning/padding. By cheat, I mean adding invisible areas to make it move where you want it.

Comment: What do you mean by "invisible areas"? Add more components? Add extra spaces inside label.text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you're adding your label. The view returned by viewForRow:forComponent: is the same width as the picker view by default, so adding the label as a subview is the correct way to get the look you want. If you want to add the label using constraints, you can do it like this,

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl.text = self.datasource[row];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    lbl.font=[UIFont PGeneralFontWithSize:22];
    [newView addSubview:lbl];

    [newView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:newView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [newView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:newView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0]];
    [newView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lbl]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"lbl":lbl}]];
    return newView;
}
```